# numpy select returns 0. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I already used this function and it worked before. I'm either blind or dunno lol:

```
conditions = [
    df_people_phone['Phone'].str.startswith('07'),
    df_people_phone['Phone'].str.contains('/07')
]

values = [
    df_people_phone['Phone'].str.extract(r'([0-9]*)'),
    df_people_phone['Phone'].str.extract(r'(\/07[0-9]*)')
]

df_people_phone['Mobile'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

Not sure but I keep getting 0 as value. If I replace the values with test strings, it works ... :(

[image: result]

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: In [**`Series.str.extract`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) calls, try non-default `expand=False`

Comment: @Parfait - yes it worked! But only after I set this condition to False for both values:
vallist = ([df_people_phone['Phone'].str.extract(r'([0-9]*)',expand=False), df_people_phone['Phone'].str.extract(r'(\/07[0-9]*)', expand=False)])

I searched online but I can't find a clear answer. What happened, why did it return 0 in the first place? Thank you!

Comment: The default, `expand=True`, returns a DataFrame with 0, 1, etc. column names. Maybe a nested one-column `DataFrame` is in that column but Jupyter shows them as zeroes!